# Why are Ksoftirqd -processes pushing my CPU-LOAD to 100%?

Tags: 11.04, suspend, hibernate, process, cpu-load

When I suspend or hibernate my laptop, the `Ksoftirqd/0` or `Ksoftirqd/1` process runs on 100% continuously. 
I have to reboot or shutdown my laptop then.
This happens in Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 and all variants.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very probable with the driver of your network card: Google reveals a lot of similar problems elsewhere: like in Finnish [this](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-350202-start-0.html).

So simply disable the unnecessary drivers or update old ones.